# Why is the remainder uniformly distributed when 1,2,3,... are divided by an irrational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let remainder $r$ be defined as
$$
r = n - pq
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the dividend , $q \in \mathbb{R}$ is the divisor, and $p = \mathrm{floor}(n/q)$.

I calculated the remainders by dividing by $\pi$ for $1,2,\dots,100000$, then I got the reminders seem to follow a uniform distribution on $[0,\pi)$.

[image: histogram of remainder]

When the divisor is rational, it's obvious that the remainder is limited to some certain values.

When it comes to a irrational divisor, it makes intuitive sense to me that the remainders can have any values on $[0,q)$, and follow a uniform distribution. However, I have no idea how to prove this.

EDIT: Added histogram.

Comment: Hint:  look at the "truncated" problem, where you require that $n≤K$.  If $K$ happens to be a multiple of q, then your claim is clear (for the truncated problem).  Otherwise it is false but only because of the small piece between $\left[\frac Kq\right] q$ and $K$.  The significance of that little piece goes to 0 as $K\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @lulu Is that sufficient to show that the if we bin the range of remainders into equal sized bins (any number of bins, say $M$), then the ratio of counts in any two bins goes to $1$ as $K \to \infty$? I.e., in particular, the limit always exists and is $1$?

Comment: Yes.  Again, this is clear if $K$ happens to be a multiple of $q$, so the only problem is that your bins may intersect that little stub piece differently.  The probability of that goes to $0$.

Comment: @lulu: I don't see where you made use of the irrationality of $q$. If your argument is correct, why doesn't it work for rational $q$?

Comment: @user2566092  I phrased that poorly.  The problem is that, if your $n$ happens to fall in the stub piece then the probability that $n$ lies in one or the other of your bins might be unequal.  But the probability of $n$ falling into the stub piece goes to $0$.

Comment: @joriki Irrationality is used in the case when $K$ is a multiple of $q$.  You are correct that this case is not clear, though I said it was.  I will revisit that.

Comment: @lulu It's still not clear to me why you can't have a weird number (something like a Louisville number) so that the ratio of counts in bins does not tend to $1$ for some appropriate choice of number of bins. Also the importance of the irrationality. I think you should probably make this an answer and fill in the formal details for the proof, and hopefully also with convergence rates for the ratios for given number of bins. It's not that I doubt you, it's just that I think whatever result/proof you have is sufficiently non-trivial to post as an answer.

Comment: @user2566092  Agreed that my quick argument was incomplete (and possibly incorrect).  I am sorting through the details.

Comment: Ok.  I see from a quick internet search that this sort of thing is generally resolved by fairly sophisticated analytic means.  But, I don't see it.  Still seems elementary to me.  I'm sure I am missing something but have posted my answer below for everyone to find the flaw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividing your formula by $q=\pi$ gives
$$
n \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}
= p + \frac{r}{\pi}
,
$$
so $p$ is the integer part,
and $\frac{r}{\pi}$ is the fractional part, of $n \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}$.
As $n$ runs through the integers, this fractional part $\frac{r}{\pi}$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$
by [Weyl's equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem),
since $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is irrational. Hence $r$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,\pi)$.

Comment: I would have to do more reading to figure out what Weyl's theorem's  "uniformly distributed" means for a countable set of sequence terms, especially since it seems that reordering the terms in a weird way will make the distribution NOT uniform. Do you happen to know, does it mean that for any finite partition of the target interval into subintervals, that if the multiples are taken in order then the proportion of multiples in each subinterval converges to be proportional to the length of the subinverval?

Comment: Yes, if the sequence of remainders is $(r_n)_1^\infty$, then the quantity "$(1/n) \times$ (the number of elements among $r_1,\dots,r_n$ that fall in the interval $I \subset [0,1)$" converges (as $n \to \infty$) to the length of the interval $I$.

Comment: Take a look at Kar's "Weyl's Equidistribution Theorem", Resonance 8:5, 30-37 (may 2003), e.g. [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02867127) for an approachable discussion.

Comment: I found [that](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kar/weyl.pdf) uploaded to Kar's website. This seems too general for my question, but it's very interesting. I also found [another explanation](http://members3.jcom.home.ne.jp/zakii/enumeration/69b_equidistribution.htm) for my pariqular question, which is written in my mother tongue, Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the answer of @HansLundmark this is Weyl's equidistribution theorem. It is an application of the [ergodic theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirkhoffsErgodicTheorem.html) combined with the theorem that an [irrational rotation of the circle is ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation#Significance), and here's some details of how to reduce it to those two theorems.

Consider the unit circle $S^1$ in the complex plane. Given $q \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the function which rotates the circle $S^1$ through the angle $\frac{2 \pi}{q}$:
$$R(z) = e^{2 \pi i / q} z
$$
Define the iterates of this function by induction to be
$$R^n(z) = R(R^{n-1}(z))
$$
Your remainder function $r(n) \in [0,q)$ is the unique function such that
$$R^n(1) = e^{2 \pi i \, r(n)/q}
$$
This sequence $R^n(1)$ is the "orbit" of $1=1+0i$ under the action of the function $R(z)$.

So your question comes down to asking: Why is the subset $\{R(x), R^2(x),\ldots,R^n(x)\}$ equally distributed in the circle as $n \to +\infty$?

Now let's bring in the ergodic theory.

Let $\mu$ denote the Borel measure on $S^1$ which assigns to an interval of angle $\alpha$ a measure of $\alpha/2\pi$. The theorem referred to above says that since $\frac{1}{q}$ is irrational, the transformation $R$ is ergodic with respect to $\mu$, and *that* means: for all $\mu$-measurable subsets $A \subset S^1$, if $R(A)=A$ then $\mu(A)=0$ or $1$.

Next we apply the Ergodic Theorem which, using that $R$ is ergodic with respect to $\mu$, says: For every $\mu$-integrable function $f : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and for $\mu$-almost every $x \in S^1$ we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(R^i(x)) = \int_{S^1} f \, d\mu
$$
So finally we can use this to see why an orbit is equally distributed. Take an angular interval $A \subset S^1$ of angle $\alpha$, and let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of $A$. The expression $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_A(R^i(x))$ (under the limit sign on the left hand side) is simply the proportion of the points in the set $\{R(x), R^2(x),\ldots,R^n(x)\}$ which lie in $A$. What "uniformly distributed" should mean is that limit of this proportion as $n \to \infty$ (the left hand side) should be equal to $\alpha/2\pi=\mu(A)=\int_{A} d\mu = \int_{S^1} \chi_A$ (the right hand side). And they are indeed equal, that is exactly what the Ergodic Theorem says.

Comment: How do you know that the particular $x$ that you start with here is among the almost every $x$ that the ergodic theorem gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm sure I am making an error but I can't spot it.  I understand (because I just looked it up) that this is typically proven by ergodic methods but it still seems elementary to me.  I expect I am making a blunder and would appreciate having someone show me where.

We wish to show that if two intervals within $[0,q]$ have the same length then the remainder is equally likely to be in either of them.

Suppose the desired interval has length $\Delta$.  Since $q$ is irrational we know that, given any positive $\Delta$ we can find an integer $m$ with $(mq)$ less than $\Delta$ (where $(x)$ denotes the remainder $x\;mod (q)$.  More generally, if $N$ is a (large) integer we can find an integer $m(N)$ such that $(m(N)q)<\frac{\Delta}{N}$.  We now partition the natural numbers by congruence classes mod (m(N)).  Take any interval $[a,b]$ of length $\Delta$. We count the number of congruence classes $m_i\;\;mod(m(N))$ such that $(m_i q)\in[a,b]$ and get $\left[\frac{a}{(m(N)q)}\right]-\left[\frac{b}{(m(N)q)}\right]$.  But this is always within $2$ of $\frac{a-b}{(m(N)q)}$ and as $N\rightarrow\infty$ we see independence of the placement of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How did you arrrive at $\left[\frac{a}{(m(N)q)}\right]-\left[\frac{b}{(m(N)q)}\right]$?

Comment: @joriki searched for the smallest (and largest) congruence class that might fit in the interval.  Did I screw up there?  How embarrassing.  Let me check.

Comment: I don't see how that's obvious. The values of $(m_iq)$ jump all over the place. It seems as if you're treating them as if they increase monotonically with $m_i$.

Comment: @joriki My "reasoning":  if $m_i=i\;mod m(n)$ then $m_i=i +km(N)$ and $qm_i=q+km(N)q$ so $qmi=km(N)q \;modq$ .  So, granted, this depends on the choice of k.  I am definitely being hasty hence careless here.  I understand that should mean I ought to stop, but I am intrigued.  I feel confident that there is an elementary proof along these lines.  I will persist.

Comment: @joriki  This is (clearly) not my field...is it generally accepted that there is no elementary proof?  I don't want to waste my time, but it seems to me that my "argument" is converging to a proof.

Comment: You're missing an $i$ in $qm_i=qi+km(N)q$, but that makes no difference. I still don't see how any of this is getting you closer to a proof, since I don't see where you've drawn any conclusions about $km(N)q\mod q$. I also don't understand what you mean by "depends on the choice of $k$", since I don't see any choice there. I don't know what's generally accepted, but I usually wouldn't spend my time looking for simple elementary proofs of things that were only proved in $1910$ :-). But of course one never knows...

Comment: @joriki  "choice of k" just meant "choice of representative for the congruence class".  Your broader point is obviously correct and someone wiser would just listen.  As it is, I will keep beating on it until I either have a proof or I understand why it is so subtle.  Silence until then.  Thanks!